# How to finds the smallest $n$ such that $I=A^0, A^1, A^2, \dots, A^n$ are linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> Let $A$ be the following $2\times 2$ matrix:
>
> $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{pmatrix}$$
>
> Find the smallest value of $n$ such that matrices $I=A^0, A^1, A^2, \dots, A^n$ are linearly dependent.

I don't quite know how to begin to answer this question since so far we have only defined linear independance for **vectors**, and these are matrices...

Comment: If $c_1A + c_2B + c_3C + c_4D =0$ happens only when $c_1=c_2=c_3=c_4=0$, then $\{A,B,C,D\}$ is called linearly independent. Doesn't matter if $A,B,C,D$ are vectors or matrices.

Comment: $n \times n$ matrices do also from vector spaces, so you can call them vectors in that sense.

Comment: Matrices are vectors. You can add them together and multiply them by real numbers just as any other vectors you're used to, and that's all it takes to make something a vector. It's just that they are usually written as a $2\times2$ square of numbers rather than a list.

Answer (score 4):

By the [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem), any matrix is a root of its own characteristic polynomial. The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is
$$
p(\lambda)=(1-\lambda)(4-\lambda)-6=\lambda^2-5\lambda-2
$$
This means that
$$
0=A^2-5A-2I
$$
and it's quite easy to show that $A$ and $I$ are linearly independent, so the answer is $n=2$.

Answer (score 2):

Calculate the powers of $A$ upto $A^2$ and write them in a row:

$$\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} \fbox{1} & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}}_{I}, \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} \fbox{1} & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix}}_{A},\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} \fbox{7} & 10 \\ 15 & 22 \end{pmatrix}}_{A^2}$$

Use the coefficient at the position $(1,1)$ in the matrix $I$ to annihilate the coefficients at $(1,1)$ in $A$ and $A^2$:

$$\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ 3 & 3 \end{pmatrix}}_{A-I},\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 10 \\ 15 & 15 \end{pmatrix}}_{A^2-7I}$$

Now notice that $A^2-7I = 5(A-I)$. Therefore:

$$0 = A^2-7I - 5(A-I) = A^2-5A-2I$$

Since $A$ is obviously not a multiple of $I$, we conclude that the smallest $n$ such that $\{I, A, \ldots, A^n\}$ is lineraly dependent is $n = 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of straigthforward computation, if you know a bit more linear algebra, one can do the following: What you are actually searching is the degree of the minimal polynomial of $A$. That is, the unitary polynomial $p(x) = x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x+a_0$ of minimal degree such that $p(A)=A^n+a_{n-1}A^{n-1}+...+a_1A+a_0=0$. Also, it is quite useful to now the not-that-easy-to-prove Cayley theorem, which states that the characterstic polynomial $\chi$ of a matrix is a multiple of the minimal polynomial, i.e. $\chi(A)=0$.

In your example, we thus know that there is a polynomial of degree $2$, the characteristic polynomial $\chi(x)=\det(xI-A)$ which satisfies $\chi(A)=0$, and as $A$ isn't of the form $aI$, we conclude that the answer is $n=2$.

Answer (score 0):

And matrices are vectors, since they are elements of the vector space of all $2\times2$ matrices. And you have$$A_0=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix},A_1=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4\end{pmatrix},A_2=\begin{pmatrix}7 & 10 \\ 15 & 22\end{pmatrix}\text{, and }A_3=\begin{pmatrix}37 & 54 \\ 81 & 118\end{pmatrix}.$$Determine their coefficients in the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$ and use that information to determine whether or not they are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

Linear independence for matrices is defined just like it is defined for vectors. You call matrices $$A_1, A_2,...,A_n$$ linearly independent iff $$C_1A_1 + C_2A_2+...+C_nA_n=0 \implies C_1=C_2=...C_n=0$$

For your matrix of    $$A= \begin{bmatrix} 1&2\\3&4\end{bmatrix}    $$
you may verify that$ A^2$ is a linear combination of $A$ and $I$.

$$ A^2 = 5A+2I $$

Thus $n=2$ is the smallest number for which $I, A,A^2$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: The question asks for the smallest n such that the matrixes are DEPENDANT. Thank you for your help, the way to go is more clear thanks to you anyway.

Comment: Thanks, check my edit.

Comment: If A^2 = 5A + 2I, it means I, A, A^2 are linearly dependant no? And then I need to prove A^3, A^2, A, I are linearly independent... Any idea on how to do this? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Yes, I, A, A^2 are  linearly dependent.  Now any other power of A can is also a linear combination of lower powers of A. For example,$ A^3 = A(A^2)= A(5A+2I)= 5A^2+2A$. So $A^3,A^2,A,I$ are linearly dependent. The smallest number of dependent is just $ A^2,A, I$ which is n=2.